# Recover files from a luks partition with extundelete

Tags: data-recovery, extundelete

I have a luks encrypted SD Card and I want to recover all deleted files from it. I have been truing with `extundelete` using the following commands:

```
extundelete --restore-directory RecoverDir/ /media/user/Cardname/
extundelete: "/media/user/Cardname/" is a directory. You need to use the raw filesystem device (or a copy thereof).
extundelete: Operation not permitted when trying to open filesystem /media/user/Cardname/
```

so I tried using using the device with:

```
extundelete --restore-directory RecoverDir/ /dev/dm-0
extundelete: Permission denied when trying to open filesystem /dev/dm-0
```

ok, this way I do not call the decrypted device, so I tried:

```
extundelete --restore-directory RecoverDir/ /dev/mapper/luks-63728377-654f-7ad0-8fa7-aa890ab098b7
extundelete: Permission denied when trying to open filesystem /dev/mapper/luks-63728377-654f-7ad0-8fa7-aa890ab098b7
```

> I changed the numbers of the filename.

when I try as `root` I get

```
extundelete: Superblock checksum does not match superblock when trying to open filesystem
```

Is there a way to get this going, or does `extundelete` not go with encrypted `luks` devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've basically tried all of the combinations except the right one. Here's what needs to be true for the tool to have a hope of working:

- Run extundelete as root
- Have the LUKS container mounted
- Point extundelete at the device file corresponding to the LUKS device (the one you pass with `mount` to mount the filesystem)

Comment: I'm on a debian "testing" with gnome desktop and the system mounts the card automatically after correct password input. With `df` i get a line `/dev/dm-0 [...] /media/user/Cardname`. Would it then be `/dev/dm-0 `?

Comment: Yes. (Though note that you don't want it to be mounted, definitely at least not rw-mounted, when you run extundelete.)

Comment: Could you please come back to this and update with some specific steps? I have the same problem but the internet is pretty scarce on how to use extundelete with encrypted lvm partitions.